# How to build a json containing system arguments?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse system arguments into a string that is injected into a json. So I have an existing json building method that is set up like this:

```
{"field1" : value, "field2" : value, "system_args" : {args_here} }
```

I want each individual argument to show up as a field under "system_args". So if the system argument was "grep hello" the corresponding json would be:

```
{"field1" : value, "field2" : value, "system_args" : {arg_0:grep, arg_1:hello, full_arg: grep hello}}
```

I am calling the below method like this (in a seperate method):

```
info = {"field1" : value, "field2" : value, "system_args" : {self.build_arg_json}}
```

I have written the following method:

```
def build_arg_json(self):
    data = []
    for index, item in enumerate(sys.argv[1:]):
        data.append({'arg_%s' % index : item})
    data.append({'full_arg': ' '.join([str(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]])})
    return json.dumps(data)
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: set(['[{"arg_0": "grep"}, {"arg_1": "hello"}, {"full_arg": "grep hello"}]']) is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Why are you trying to construct a JSON string to stick in the dict, instead of just putting a dict in the dict and letting `json.dumps` serialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop thinking about how to build JSON, and think about the value that you want to JSON-encode, and things are usually a lot simpler.

The closest valid thing to what you show in your example is:

```
{'arg_0': 'grep', 'arg_1': 'hello', 'full_arg': 'grep hello'}
```

So, you want a dict. Don't try to build a list and then figure out how to turn that list into a JSON string or a dict or whatever; just build a dict:

```
system_args = {}
for index, item in enumerate(sys.argv[1:]):
    system_args['arg_%s' % index] = item
system_args['full_arg'] = ' '.join([str(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]])
```

But `sys.argv` is already a list of strings, so you can make that last line a lot simpler:

```
system_args['full_arg'] = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
```

And finally, don't `json.dumps` this. You want to insert it in another dictionary, which you're going to `json.dumps` later, so just return it as a dictionary:

```
return system_args
```

And now, since it returns a dict, which is the value you want for `system_args`, you don't have to put it inside braces (which would turn it into a one-element set); just use it as-is:

```
info = {"field1" : value, "field2" : value, "system_args" : self.build_arg_json()}
```